# PyQt5: How to display list in QMessageBox? TypeError: argument 3 has unexpected type 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I'm trying to display a list in a QMessageBox
I keep getting error:

> TypeError: question(QWidget, str, str, buttons:
>   Union[QMessageBox.StandardButtons, QMessageBox.StandardButton] =
>   QMessageBox.StandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No),
>   defaultButton: QMessageBox.StandardButton = QMessageBox.NoButton):
>   argument 3 has unexpected type 'list'

Here's the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'List manipulation'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 325
        self.height = 300
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # Create textbox
        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 20)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 200)

        # Create a button in the window
        self.button = QPushButton('Show text', self)
        self.button.move(20, 230)

        # connect button to function on_click
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
        xlist = textboxValue.splitlines()
        xlist_final=[]
        for xitem in xlist:
            if xitem.find("abc") != -1:
                xlist_final.append(xitem)
    QMessageBox.question(self, 'List manipulation', xlist_final, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
    self.textbox.setText("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
Input on the box are these lines:

```
abc
xabcx
def
zabc
ghi
ooabc
abccc
```

I want to filter the list above to display only words contain 'abc'
the result would be:

```
abc
xabcx
zabc
ooabc
abccc
```

I already wrote the code in the python file above as follows

```
textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
            xlist = textboxValue.splitlines()
            xlist_final=[]
            for xitem in xlist:
                if xitem.find("abc") != -1:
                    xlist_final.append(xitem)
```

the problem is how to display it on the Qmessagebox to contain the list, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to concatenate the strings with `\n` using `join()` as shown below:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
    xlist = textboxValue.splitlines()
    xlist_final = [xitem for xitem in xlist if xitem.find("abc") != -1]
    QMessageBox.question(self, 'List manipulation', "\n".join(xlist_final), QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
    self.textbox.clear()
```

[image]